# Как спускаться вглубь словаря python с неизвестным количеством веток?

Tags: python, json, dict, словарь

Нужно создать словарь: *{'дом': {'окно': None}, 'озеро': None}*.
Имея строки с "путями": *['дом/окно', 'озеро']*.

Но мы **не знаем** сколько ветвей "спуска", чтобы указать ключи *['дом']['окно']*.
Как можно **создать/читать** словарь python имея лишь строку с путём?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Сделайте рекурсию и используйте метод `update`:

```
paths = ['дом/окно/стекло', 'озеро/вода', "42"]

def nested(a:str, sep:str):
    if sep not in a:
        return {a: None}
    key, val = a.split(sep, 1)
    return {key: nested(val, sep)}
    
res = {}
[res.update(nested(x, "/")) for x in paths]
print(res)
```

> {'дом': {'окно': {'стекло': None}}, 'озеро': {'вода': None}, '42': None}

Answer (score 0):

С помощью `eval()` можно, но это может быть опасно, если в строке содержится код.

```
paths_list = ['квартира/комната/мебель/стол/стул', 'дом/окно', 'озеро', 'река/водопад/переправа']

dict_list = []
for path in paths_list:
    path = "{'"+path.replace("/", "':{'")+"':None"
    dict_count = path.count("{")
    path = path+"}"*dict_count
    dict_list.append(eval(path))
print(dict_list)
```

Вывод:

```
[{'квартира': {'комната': {'мебель': {'стол': {'стул': None}}}}}, {'дом': {'окно': None}}, {'озеро': None}, {'река': {'водопад': {'переправа': None}}}]
```